# Does disabling interrupt automatically disable CPU scheduling?

Tags: operating-system, scheduling, interrupt

Hey guys, is it true that all the process/thread scheduling will be disabled if interrupt is disabled? What I know is interrupt includes clock interrupt and other interrupts. CPU scheduling(e.g., Round-Robin) is based on clock interrupt. If that's disabled, scheduling is disabled as well and the current thread continues executing until it yeilds CPU. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

If it's pure priority-based scheduling instead of RR (considering real-time systems), and a lower priority thread disables the interrupt, then a higher priority thread arrives, will the lower priority thread be preempted?

This leads me to think about the protection in operating system. What if some user intentionally write a virus to disable interrupts? Probably he cannot do that in user mode, what if he writes a program running in kernal mode and does that bad stuff? Can he do this?

I'm not expecting a general rule across all platforms. So please let me know what the situation is on the platform you know, thanks.

Comment: There is generally no limit on the bad stuff in kernel mode. Anything in kernel mode can trash the control registers (example: change the page table base address to some garbage value). That is why you need to be an administrator to add drivers. You should say which operating system and architecture you mean, if any.

Comment: Processors commonly used in embedded systems will include a watchdog timer. x86 is also capable of watchdog timer, connected to NMI. However, a malicious program can just disable the watchdog timer and disable interrupts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, answer to your question is architecture dependant. Let us assume that we are talking about i386 or x86_64 as these are the most popular processor architectures these days.

User-mode program cannot clear interrupt flag because it requires CPL (current priviledge level) 0. User-mode programs never have CPL 0. In Linux for example, user-mode programs run with CPL 2 and only kernel runs with CPL 0. Therefore you cannot write a virus that would disable interrupts and thus disable scheduling. In Windows, if I am not mistaken, programs run with CPL 1.

On the other hand running code in kernel (in just any operating system) requires administrative rights, which allow you to do anything you want anyway, so disabling interrupts in kernel mode doesn't make any sense.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: one thing about disabling interrupts in kernel mode is that you're guaranteed no other thread(e.g., some high priority auto-virus thread) can take over CPU and kills the virus so that the virus have enough time to do whatever it wants. Does that make sense?

Comment: User mode programs, in Linux i386, run at CPL=3, not 2. On the other hand, an user program CAN disable interrupts if running by root. Root processes can use the iopl() system call to lower the IOPL level to 3, so a process with CPL=3 can use the CLI and STI instructions, which are IOPL sensitive, not CPL sensitive.